# SQL / Crystal Report : Split row into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Is it possible to split row based on the calculation result?

Sample as below:

Datatable: SalesOrder

```
ItemCode   |  Qty  |  CartonS  |  CartonM  |  CartonL
ItemA      |  22   |  1-2      |  3-6      |  7-10
ItemB      |  15   |  1-4      |  5-10     |  NULL
ItemC      |  32   |  1-2      |  3-7      |  8-10
```

What result I want:

```
Item Code  |  Carton No. |  Carton Type  |  Carton Qty
ItemA      |  01-02      |  CartonL      |  2
ItemA      |  03-03      |  CartonS      |  1
ItemB      |  04-05      |  CartonM      |  2
ItemC      |  06-08      |  CartonL      |  3
ItemC      |  09-09      |  CartonS      |  1
```

For ItemA, order qty is 22 and I can pack with 2 qty CartonL and 1 qty CartonS

For ItemB, order qty is 15 and I can pack with 2 qty CartonM

For ItemC, order qty is 32 and I can pack with 3 qty CartonL and 1 qty CartonS

I will create a Crystal Report and retrieve data from a SQL. Is it possible to get the above result?

---

Thanks Siva & Arvo, at this moment I have no idea to calculate the qty :(

Because three types of carton are not same for every items.

Refer to the sample, ItemA's CartonS can store 1-2 qty but ItemB can store 1-4 qty.

That means if I order the same qty for each Item. Such as order 3 qty:

For ItemA I need to use CartonM instead of CartonS

For ItemB I can use CartonS

Thanks!

Anmi

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but suggest you try cross tab by placing columns in rows part and rows in columns part.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've modified my question. Actually I've no idea to calculate the qty.

Comment: @Anmi I am sorry to say that couldn't understand the exact requirement so couldn't give you the required solution but one thing I can suggest to the extent I understood. create columns as required and the I would suggest to create the formulas using the If condition as required.

Comment: Thanks Siva, I know how to calculate the Qty now.

Answer (score 0):

Make three Detail sections, one for each Carton type. Suppress unneeded sections, calculate Carton quantities on the fly - I hope you have some algorithm for this?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've modified my question. Actually I've no idea to calculate the qty.